# d3 map with topojson not showing the shapes on the canvas

Tags: d3.js, topojson

I am new to d3 and topojson. Trying to render a map on a ionic-angular app. It seems that the canvas is populated properly, but the shapes are not visible :( Can please someone help? Here is the screenshot of the dom.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Oops.. My bad.. The container had to be SVG, I have used CANVAS :(